# Writing apps for the Apple TV 2G

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak

My company (a mobile dev house) has a number of HD TVs that we purchased some Apple TV 2Gs for (which are jailbroken). We use them to display slideshows of products, information, etc, as well as video playback.

Since we develop iOS apps as part of our business I'd really like to have a go at writing something for the Apple TV to use on our internal monitors. What I don't have is any idea of where to start - for obvious reasons the majority of our work is writing apps for app store distribution, so developing software for jailbroken iOS is new to me.

Also, the majority of resources out there are for developing jailbroken apps are for iPad/iPhone devices - I guess not many people are interested in writing apps for the ATV2, probably because not many jailbroken ATVs are out in the wild. Does anyone have any good starting points for me to begin with - an experienced iOS developer wanting to look into writing apps for jailbroken devices, *especially* the Apple TV? More in terms of general approach.

Comment: If you are member of an Apple Developer Program I'd delete this question if I were you. Otherwise: good luck :)

Comment: Fortunately, it's not under this name :P I figure it's worth a try, anyway

Comment: How about connecting iPod Touches to those monitors? You'd get the same ability to display stuff on a platform your team is familiar with.. :)

Comment: Well, in the name of hackery I guess :) Since writing this question I took a look at the XCode project for the XMBC ATV port, but still interested to see if there are any other resources out there.

Comment: Apple has not release any SDK for running on ATV2 device.

Comment: You're not reading my question: I *know* Apple haven't released an SDK. That doesn't stop people from *developing* for it, and I'm looking for resources in that direction. People were writing apps for the iPhone before iOS 2.0 came out, you know...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To develops 'apps' for Apple TV2, you will need to build them in a frappliance. It can be done with a Xcode template.
Download your helloWorld template here
or direct from Bile’s github (new version) : https://github.com/lechium/HelloWorld_ATVBlack/downloads
Xcode is line by line explained in : http://greenpois0n.com/2011/04/16/27/

Another HelloWorld base can be found  here https://github.com/b0bben/Plex-ATV-Plugin (Base for Plex created by b0bboen)

A more recent HelloWorld from Michael Gile can be found here https://github.com/mgile/atvHelloWorld

Or just another one here : https://github.com/lzell/AppleTVProjectTemplate

I also tried to create some simple frappliances here : http://imho.nu/Home/

Good luck developing

Gr.
MACasuba

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the source for the Apple TV client for Plex can help with example code:

[Plex ATV plugin](https://github.com/quiqueck/Plex-ATV-Plugin)

(More info on usage, not development though, [in the Plex wiki](http://wiki.plexapp.com/index.php/Apple_TV_Plex_Client_Install))

Comment: I was looking at the website and I am not sure what the plugin does?

Comment: The plugin makes a jailbroken ATV2 into a Plex client.

Comment: Then this is the correct answer and you should received the bounty.  :)

Comment: :-) At least it's a starting point for someone wanting to write code running on the ATV2.

Comment: I guess it's a start. Jesse's answer should also help in that regard. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this report](http://www.appletvhacks.net/2010/10/05/new-apple-tv-set-up-for-installing-applications-installation-works/), you can actually install normal iOS apps on your AppleTV. Here's what I would do:

1. Begin creating a normal iOS app
   (maybe some kind of hello, world
   app)
2. Try to install it on the Apple
   TV
3. If it works, then you can
   manipulate your views in XCode to
   look right on the ATV.

Answer (score 1):

NitoTV (first JB app developer for ATV 2  has a hello world starting app, the source is on the internet. http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1035345

Answer (score 0):

As you know, writting apps for the Apple TV is not currently alowed by Apple. But, the iPad and current iPhones/iPods have a TV output so you can develop special app and use them instead.

With the iPad 2 (and iPhone 5) you will also have the TV output for every app (in screen copy) so you can also use that. And this will be easier and more documented than trying to develop on a jaibroken non suported device.

Comment: Not really my question though: I'm interested in finding out more about developing specifically for the ATV platform. Clearly it's possible - look at XBMC - but it would have been nice if there was something other than the raw source to look through. But I admit it's a rather niche development requirement!